# Problems with Automatic Replies (Out of Office) in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I click the Automatic Replies button on the File->Info page in Outlook 2010 I get an error telling me the server is unavailable, but the server is available, as I can send and receive mail.  My email account is strictly online, with no local inbox, i.e. no .pst file, connecting to Exchange server.

What could be causing this?  I suspect that automatic replies is some sort of additional service that I need to configure in Outlook, or inj Exchange server.  If the latter, I will ask a more specific question on ServerExchange.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Arjan, nope, I have since left the company though, so I doubt I ever will.